# Problems with ajax, log function doesn't work and other functions dont either

Tags: php, ajax

i've recently started working with ajax so bare with me as I have very little knownledge around it.

I receive the data that I need, however ajax doesn't function properly for some reason.

```
$("#ajax").on("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'dataworks.php?action=getcity&country_id=2',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',

    sucess: function(data) {
      console.log("x");
      data.each(function(key) {
        $("#citysec").append("<option value=" + data[key]['city_id'] + ">" + data[key]['city'] + "</option>");
      })
    },
    error: function(jqxHr, textStatus, err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
});
```

ajax code

```
if($_GET){
  $action = $_GET['action'];
  switch ($action) {
    case 'getcity':
      $res = getCity($_GET['country_id']);
      //echo $res;
      echo json_encode($res);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function getData($query){

  $username = "";
  $servername = "";
  $password = "";
  $databaseName = "";
  
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databaseName);
  if($conn->connect_error){
      die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
  };

  $ret = array();
  $res = $conn->query($query);

  if($res->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }

    $conn->close();

    return $ret;
  }
}
```

php code that works directly with ajax

[image: Response]

For some reason nothing is printed in console neither err or x

Could someone enlighten me on what is the issue? thanks.

Comment: In *dataworks.php* does `getCity($_GET['country_id'])` return a proper response?

Comment: I think the function that is executed when the `AJAX` call is successful is called [`complete`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=by%20a%20GET.-,complete,-Type%3A%20Function). Anyway, that depends on the version of `jQuery` you're using.

Comment: @ths No it doesn't, these callback options haven't changed. `success` is called after successful calls, `error` is called after failing calls, and `complete` is called after both types.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but the docs has basically the same description for both functions (which might seem confusing). Anyway, the version of `jQuery` being used could be helpful though.

Comment: `country_id=2` is not a valid MySQL query. `$query` needs to be something like `SELECT city FROM tableName WHERE country_id = 2`

Comment: `sucess: function(data) {` Is "success" misspelled in your code to? Or just the question above. Make sure your code is: `success: function(data) {`